# pion::net HTTPServer persistent connections

Tags: c++, http, boost, boost-asio

I'm working on a low-latency high-throughput, minimalistic HTTP server (almost real-time message switch).

I'm very fond of pion::net, and I've seen numerous references that it supports persistent connections (thus potentially saving the whole TCP ordeal):

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-HTTP-td2637928.html

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to use pion::net that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persistence is a property of [TCPConnection](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_t_c_p_connection.html) (see the [setLifecycle](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_t_c_p_connection.html#dc0cd1d7104cb11cd3a71f5b41f1bb0e) method). So if you choose to go the [WebServer](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_web_server.html) / [Webservice](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_web_service.html) route set the Lifecycle property accordingly in [WebService::operator()](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/net/doc/html/classpion_1_1net_1_1_web_service.html#ea1b583bdec0f4ae2c9f3720cfc8ecbf).
Also, since you're talking HTTP you should set the connection persistence according to the info the client sends you (namely the HTTP version and the value of the `Connection` header).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - using the writer->getTCPConnection()->setLifecycle(TCPConnection::LIFECYCLE_KEEPALIVE);
did the trick :)